# How to sync large data

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview

Hi to all Android heroes out there, I have been facing this interesting problem which I am trying to explain here

I have a simple requirement of showing a large amount of data in recycler view in a grid view which I am achieving using the Paging library provided by Android Jetpack.
I am using Single Source Of Truth pattern in which data fetched from the server is stored in Room DB first and then the database is observed for any changes.
The data I am fetching is sorted. It starts with A then B and so on as I scroll down

Now the requirement is there is a scroller besides the recycler view which contains all the alphabet listed down in vertical fashion giving the user the functionality
to jump to any alphabet directly instead of scrolling down to reach it.
The total rows of data starting from A to Z are around 100,000.
Now suppose the user is scrolling in normal fashion and is on the data starting with A letter, suddenly he taps on P alphabet from the scroller then the app
should show the data starting with P and then it should resume it's the behavior of scrolling i.e if user scrolls up then he should see data starting from O and
if he scrolls down then he should start seeing data with Q and so on.

The next requirement is since I am using local DB via Room then I should update data only when it gets updated saving the hits to the server.
What should be the ideal way to sync data with server considering the fact that minimum hits go to the server and we do not have old data in local DB
How can I achieve above-mentioned functionalities in an optimized way